# Group rows in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to group rows which is having same Name in `DataGridView` on Windows Forms below is the image what I want to implement.

Is it possible to implement below without using any third party tool ?

[image: sample]

Comment: No, there is no way of doing this easily with the standard control.

Comment: @Killercam: yeah, me too haven't found any solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using the functionality of MSFlexGrid's MergeCells property of vertical cell merging instead of row grouping as explained in this article [DataGridView Grouping in C#/VB.NET: Two Recipes](http://10tec.com/articles/datagridview-grouping-two-recipes.aspx). In this example, rows which belong to a group are joined visually using cells merged vertically - instead of using classical horizontal group rows.

[image]

```
protected override void OnCellPainting(DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs args)
{
  base.OnCellPainting(args);

  args.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom =
    DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;

  // Ignore column and row headers and first row
  if (args.RowIndex < 1 || args.ColumnIndex < 0)
    return;

  if (IsRepeatedCellValue(args.RowIndex, args.ColumnIndex))
  {
    args.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top =
      DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
  }
  else
  {
    args.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Top;
  }
}
```

Comment: i think we are only creating a illusion here by removing border.

Comment: But isn't it what you want to achieve without using any third party libraries/controls?

Comment: yes, i want to do the same but after this. i want to put a checkbox for check all same group items and perform some operation. so this is not the solution all though you are right we can have the same look as displaying in image. Thanks for the help..:)

Comment: No worries. I was using the original question which did not factor in the checkbox requirement that you later specified in the comment.

Comment: but how to make it the merged-look-like-cell is  centered vertically @chridam?

Answer (score 9):

in the DataGridView place the following code in the

```
dgvProduct_CellFormatting Event

If e.RowIndex > 0 And e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
                If dgvProduct.Item(0, e.RowIndex - 1).Value = e.Value Then
                    e.Value = ""
                ElseIf e.RowIndex < dgvProduct.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                    dgvProduct.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
                End If
End If
```

All done!

Enjoy

[image]

Comment: Simple, definitely a hack, but BRILLIANT! Great idea.

Answer (score 4):

To supplement the (chosen) answer, here's the full code. The unmentioned idea is a class extending the DataGridView class.

```
public class GroupByGrid : DataGridView
    {

        protected override void OnCellFormatting(
           DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs args)
        {
            // Call home to base
            base.OnCellFormatting(args);

            // First row always displays
            if (args.RowIndex == 0)
                return;


            if (IsRepeatedCellValue(args.RowIndex, args.ColumnIndex))
            {
                args.Value = string.Empty;
                args.FormattingApplied = true;
            }
        }

        private bool IsRepeatedCellValue(int rowIndex, int colIndex)
        {
            DataGridViewCell currCell =
               Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex];
            DataGridViewCell prevCell =
               Rows[rowIndex - 1].Cells[colIndex];

            if ((currCell.Value == prevCell.Value) ||
               (currCell.Value != null && prevCell.Value != null &&
               currCell.Value.ToString() == prevCell.Value.ToString()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnCellPainting(
           DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnCellPainting(args);

            args.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom =
               DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;

            // Ignore column and row headers and first row
            if (args.RowIndex < 1 || args.ColumnIndex < 0)
                return;

            if (IsRepeatedCellValue(args.RowIndex, args.ColumnIndex))
            {
                args.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top =
                   DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
            }
            else
            {
                args.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Top;
            }
        }
    }
```

[source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a44622c0-74e1-463b-97b9-27b87513747e/windows-forms-data-controls-and-databinding-faq?forum=winformsdatacontrols#faq8) courtesy of social.msdn.microsoft

Answer (score 0):

at first time create without subgroup.
if user click btn_plus on grid insert data to grid