# Error when using dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have to show `dataGridView1` as

```
SN    Name        Subject       Topic            Subtopic
1.    Mr.SK Jha   Physics       Optics           Diffraction
                                                 Interference
                                Mechanics        MKS
                                Electromagnetic
2.    Mr.XYZ     Chemistry      Inorganic        Ethene
```

Here the topic is the same from subject_id and it may have many data not specified as fixed.

I have seen many [reference](https://sites.google.com/site/learning6329/asp-net/gridview-merge-cells)  but it gives `GridViewRow` as error.

I am using Visual Studio 2013, framework 4.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group rows in DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486858/group-rows-in-datagridview)

Comment: The example is ASP. You are doing Winforms, right? (Please add the tag!) - DataGridViews do not suport grouping. There are only ways to make them look like they do.. One would be to use transparent text in the repeating cells..

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want the DGV to look like a grouped table, with the repeating values suppressed.

This is a routine to paint the repeating cells transparent:

```
static void PaintGrouped(DataGridView dgv)
{
    if (dgv.Rows.Count < 2) return;
    if (dgv.Columns.Count < 2) return;
    for (int row = 1; row < dgv.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
        bool suppressing = dgv[0, row].Value.Equals(dgv[0, row - 1].Value);
        for (int col = 1; col < dgv.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            bool equal = dgv[col, row].Value.Equals(dgv[col, row - 1].Value);
            suppressing = suppressing && equal;
            dgv[col, row].Style.ForeColor = supressing ? Color.Transparent : Color.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that all values are still in place and be changed or copied. After any changes you should re-apply the routine! Also note that I have decided to never suppress the 1st column.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest method is to make the datasource a datatable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("SN", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Topic", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Subtopic", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1.", "Mr.SK Jha", "Physics", "Optics", "Diffraction Interference" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "", "", "", "Mechanics", "MKS" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "", "", "", "Electromagnetic" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Mr.XYZ", "Chemistry", "Inorganic", "Ethene" });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: This will not allow you to access the individual cells any longer.

Comment: TaW : Please explain your issue.  You can access the cells in the datatable or the datagridview.

Comment: Really? Are you sure that you can access all three values "Optics Diffraction Interference" separately? I would expect that this should be possible, but I may be wrong..

Comment: Look at the column names.  It is not clear which strings go into which columns and if any cells are null.  Don't blame the solution where the inputs are not clearly defined.  The solution is good.

Comment: Agreed, the question is not 100% clear and your solution is solid, at least if it applies to the problem. The OP has to decide.. I had looked at both his link (about merging cells) and the duplicate link about grouping a DGV.

Comment: I have used dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; on a function and this function is used to call on page_load. The data came from query from database. it is not static. How could i save data on db so that i get data on my desired type

Comment: `page_load` ?? Are you using ASP after all?? __Please always tag your question with the appropriate target!!__

Comment: What database are you using.  You should use a DataAdapter to load the datatable.

Comment: See webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx.  I would use adapter.Fill(datatable) instead of dataset.  A dataset contains multiple datatables and you only have one datatable.

Comment: Please jdweng or TaW  can i contact you using gmail or other medium. So that i can give image and all my code. I could not post image here.. ;) . Or contact me kapeel4@gmail.com

Comment: Won't help without database or at least the definition of the tables in the database.