# how to group rows in datagridview on Query in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Still has my problem on how i group rows in datagridview after executing SELECT Statement. I just want to make my datagridview to display data like the image i uploaded, if you would mind to take a look at the image below;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJvum.jpg)

I've also tried this code but it does not do the same like the image;

```
    Private Sub dgvCurriculum_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvCurriculum.CellFormatting

    If e.RowIndex > 0 And e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        If dgvCurriculum.Item(0, e.RowIndex - 1).Value = e.Value Then
            e.Value = ""
        ElseIf e.RowIndex < dgvCurriculum.Rows.Count - 1 Then
            dgvCurriculum.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I know this sounds tricky but, i couldn't find another way on how to do it. I'm just new in vb.net.

Comment: Why the C# tag if you are working with vb.Net?

Comment: What you're showing there is a matter of merging cells in the same row, so that is what you should search the web for.  You'll find information on that topic with the right keywords.

Comment: I tagged C# maybe to find additional information on how to do it. and maybe i could convert C# code to vb.net. I've searched in the web and i found the exact case with my datagridview in this link "http://aspalliance.com/723_Enhancing_the_DataGrid_with_Grouped_Rows_and_Subheadings"  but i do not know how to do it with vb.net. I really need help to do it please share me some code.

Comment: @Diaval - so you have found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30755561/6305294 but it does not do quite what you want, so you want another answer? You need clearly state in your question what other answers you have tried.

Comment: @Alex- Yes, You're right.. I just want to make it as a subheader. for example, the code i 'd showed, instead of merging cells with the same value, i want to make the duplicate values in a specific row as a Sub-Heading or rows like the result of this link: http://aspalliance.com/723_Enhancing_the_DataGrid_with_Grouped_Rows_and_Subheadings If it is possible in vb.net.