# what is the next step, i have the code but i dont know what to do next?

Tags: c#

im new to c# and i'm trying to fill my datagridview with data from the database and make a groupby on certain column.

for ex:

i have a datagridview that contains : field, fullname and worker_id.

i want to get the data from database and group them according to the field name.

```
public void FillFullSchedule()
    {


        using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            sqlcon.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.FullScheduleData", sqlcon);
            //SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            fullScheduleDG.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                int n = fullScheduleDG.Rows.Add();
                fullScheduleDG.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = dr[1].ToString();
                fullScheduleDG.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = dr[0].ToString();
                fullScheduleDG.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = dr[2].ToString();

            }

        }

    }
```

no problem with that.

i have the code for grouping the data from this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44807088/10534001

but i dont know how to use it. what should i do ?? i dont know the next step.

is it to add events to cellformating or something like that or what ?

Comment: Take a look at the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114635/how-to-bind-datatable-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp

Comment: Don't fill grid, but simply bind it.

Comment: `fullScheduleDG .DataSource = dt`, will be same result as you doing it manually in the loop.

Comment: Use grouped datasource or inherited datagridview instead of datagridview. In Initilize method replace `new DataGridView` with `new GroupByGrid`.

Comment: Don't bind grid to `DataTable` but rather to `DataView`. You can sort, search using data view. DataTable should be just a storage, view should be source

Comment: @T.S., that's not good advice. When you bind a `DataTable`, the data comes from its `DefaultView` anyway, which is a `DataView`. Good advice would be to bind the `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to the grid.

Comment: If you're trying to implement the accepted answer in that thread then you need to create your own class that inherits `DataGridView` and then add the code provided to add custom behaviour. You can then use an instance of your class on your form instead of a standard `DataGridView`.

Comment: my question is how to call that class https://stackoverflow.com/a/44807088/10534001  with their functions to be applied on my datagridview?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I've done that. But I also used `DataView`. MSDN: *"Represents a databindable, customized view of a DataTable for sorting, filtering, searching, editing, and navigation."*

Comment: @T.S., I know what a `DataView` is but every `DataTable` already has one associated with it - its `DefaultView` - and that's already where the data comes from when you bind a `DataTable` anyway. Binding should be done via a `BindingSource` anyway, and it provides the same sorting and filtering as the `DataView` - it actually does it via the `DataView` under the hood - plus more besides. There's no reason to touch a `DataView` directly in this circumstances.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I don't remember exactly, but there was some limitation what you can do in one view. I think, number of fields displayed or something like this. So, you can have multiple data views and change them based on selected options. that was easy to implement using data views. the default view had an issue that something couldn't be changed in it once view is created.

Comment: @T.S., sure, if you need multiple views of the same table then you need to create multiple `DataViews` explicitly but there's no indication that multiple views are required in this particular case so there's no reason to create a `DataView` or use the `DefaultView` directly. Like I said, the data you see in the UI already comes from the `DefaultView` if you bind the `DataTable`, so it is still very useful - necessary even - but there's no need to touch it directly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Build a class with your 3 desired fields and a BindingList for the data to populate within the DataGrid.

```
public class yourClassName
{
     public string field { get; set; }
     public string fullname { get; set; }
     public int worker_id { get; set; }
}
public class yourMainClass
{
     public BindingList<yourClassName> yourDataForGrid { get; }
     public yourMainClass(//this is a constructor.  your params go here)
     {
          yourDataForGrid = GetDataForGrid(//your params here)
     }
}
```

In your load method, create a new object and bind the fields:

```
yourClassName tempThing;
dgNameOfYourDataGrid.DataSource = new BindingSource(tempThing.yourDataForGrid, null);
```

Create the method that I called in the constructor that loads the BindingList:

```
 public static BindingList<yourClassName> GetDataForGrid(//your params here)
 {
      BindingList<yourClassName> tempList = new BindingList<yourClassName>();

      //your sql code to build a dataset goes here
      //foreach row in your dataset
      {
           yourClassName row = new yourClassName();
           row.field = //insert value for field
           row.fullname = //insert value for fullname
           row.worker_id = //insert value for worker_id

           tempList.Add(row);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Ok till now you told me how to do all that above but where should i use the code in this link : stackoverflow.com/a/44807088/10534001 for merging the cells of the datagrid? If you check that link you will find exactly what I need but the thing is that i dont know how to do it step by step