# Change data table format

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a System.Data.DataTable, sorted in ascending order by column `Sector` like this:

[image]

I dont need to repeat for each row the `Sector` value (first column) but i need to write it in a blank row only at the first occurrence and under that all the rows with the same `Sector` but without this value, like this

[image]

How can I do in C#?

Comment: This is a *display* concern, not a data table/Linq concern. This will be a feature of whatever DataGrid UI component you’re using. Check your component’s documentation for “grouping” or “subtables”.

Comment: "Data Table" can mean many things in different contexts.  What do you mean by "data table"?  A table in a database?  A System.Data.DataTable? A `List<T>` for some T that represents a row of data? Some sort of UI grid full of data? Something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group rows in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486858/group-rows-in-datagridview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("Sector", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("IPC", typeof(long));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Analyst", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Issuer Group", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Senority", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Mkt Value", typeof(long));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Nom Value", typeof(long));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Issue Group", typeof(string));

            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Agencies", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA"});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Agencies", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Agencies", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Consumer", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Energy", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Energy", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA" });

            DataTable dt2 = dt1.Clone();

            var groups = dt1.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Sector")).ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                long mktValue = group.Sum(x => x.Field<long>("Mkt Value"));
                long nomValue = group.Sum(x => x.Field<long>("Nom Value"));

                dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { group.Key, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, mktValue, nomValue });
                foreach (DataRow row in group)
                {
                    object[] data = row.ItemArray;
                    data[0] = DBNull.Value;
                    dt2.Rows.Add(data);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its also possible having in the row with the "Sector" the sum of all "Mkt Value" and "Nom Value" belonging to that sector.? Like Agencies in Mkt Value and Nom Value have the sum of the three rows who had that sector?